# source raise "no editor command: command"

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

While developing vim plugin, in my `.vim` file I tried typing the following commands:

```
:source %
:source /PATH/TO/FILE/plugin.vim
```

I am sure there are no syntax errors. As I tried by keeping plugin content blank. (Attached the code in last). But I m getting the following error when I open a text file and run `*:Command*`

Error:

```
Not an editor command: Command
```

*plugin.vim* Code:

```
function! Execute()

endfunction
command! Command call Execute()
```

Where am I missing out?

*Note*: I am EMACS guy, new to vim.

Comment: What is your error? I don't see it on your question.

Comment: I have updated the error part in the question. Please have a look!

Comment: I don't reproduce your error, is the plugin.vim file you are mentioning the same file as % in this context ?

Comment: Yes.. when I am inside plugin.vim I typed :source %

Comment: What is your vim version? Also have a look at http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file

Comment: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4

Comment: Are you opening the text file and running `:Command` in the same vim instance or are you closing vim, then opening the text file and trying to run the command?  If the plugin hasn't been sourced in the current vim instance then the `Command` command won't have been defined.  While editing the text file run `:scriptnames`.  If your plugin isn't listed there then it hasn't been sourced.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The problem was with setting the path in rtp file. Just sourcing that file won't help I guess!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to update the run time patch variable (runtimepath or rtp) in vimrc. Should update path to the directory of the plugin. Then source `~/.vimrc` file or reopen the file in vim. Include the following line in `~/.vimrc`. Sometimes just sourcing won't work. So just reopen the file.

set rtp+=/PATH/TO/FILE/

then open any file in vi and running the Command would work!